# pythonのlxml ElementTree におけるXpathを利用したxmlファイル読み込みの挙動

Tags: python3

python3でlxml ElementTree を利用しています。
10000KBサイズ程度のxmlファイルをparseして、
Xpathを利用してノードを抽出しています。

全くコードを変更しないで呼び出しを行っているのですが
正常にデータが取得できる場合とエラーになる場合があります。
エラー内容は、
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
となります。

正常にデータを取得できるため、xpathの記述は正常だと思われます。

どのような原因が考えられるでしょうか？

読み込むxmlファイルはローカルPCのフォルダに配置されており、
デスクトップ（Windows）からコマンドプロンプトで対象のpythonファイルを実行しています。

Comment: 再現する手順をご提示いただかないと回答は難しいでしょう。同じファイルを読み込ませたら必ずエラーになりますか？それとも同じファイルでも正常な場合とエラーになる場合があるのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
全く同じ‌​ファイルを読みこんだ場合でも、
正常な場合とエラーになる場合‌​があります。

該当の箇所だけ抽出いたしました。


from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(filename)
xpathobjects = tree.xpath(xpath_query)

filename と　xpath_query　は全く同じものを呼び出し元から渡しています。

Comment: だとするとlxmlのバグかWindows用にコンパイルした時に想定外の問題が起きているのだと思います。lxmlはどのようにインストールしましたか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
少し前にインストールしたので正確には覚えていませんが、コマンドプロンプトから
'pip install lxml'
でインストールしたかと思います。

Comment: 別の方法でXmlファイルを格納することにいたしました。